# DuplicateFileException while building the apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 on windows 8 and an error occures while building the app.
First, during the gradle build when you launch the IDE, I have these warnings:

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for debugAndroidTest as it may be conflicting with the internal 
version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.
```

Then during the apk build there are 2 warnings and this error:

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is 
ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android.

Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied 
in APK META-INF/LICENSE
File1: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-
core\2.2.3\1a0113da2cab5f4c216b4e5e7c1dbfaa67087e14\jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
File2: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-
annotations\2.2.3\527fece4f23a457070a36c371a26d6c0208e1c3\jackson-
annotations-2.2.3.jar
File3: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files- 2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3.6\cf8bacbf0d476c7f2221f861269365b664
47f7ec\httpmime-4.3.6.jar
File4: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-
databind\2.2.3\3ae380888029daefb91d3ecdca3a37d8cb92bc9\jackson-databind-
2.2.3.jar
File5: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files- 2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\e876a79d561e5c6207b78d347e198c8c45
31a5e5\httpcore-4.4.3.jar
```

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use packaginOptions in your 'app' build.gradle file, after your buildToolsVersion :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your **buiild.gradle**,

It comes because you are not excluding the `META-INF/LICENSE` file which exists in more than one of your dependencies

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
    // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
    // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

**OR** enable multiDex

```
defaultConfig {

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
```

Comment: I added your code to the build.gradle file but it still gives me 2 duplicated files :
File1: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\b31526a230871fbe285fbcbe2813f9c0839ae9b0\httpcore-4.4.3.jar

File2: C:\Users\giorgia\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.2\22b4c53dd9b6761024258de8f9240c3dce6ea368\httpmime-4.5.2.jar

Comment: Have you tried , deleting build folder in App folder , and then rebuilding project?

Comment: Just tried, nothing changes... I think I will give up on this Spoonacular API

Comment: @GiorgiaCampardo whats the status of your apps multidex??

Comment: Didn't know about the problem of the 64k limit, I'll check and then let you know 